# SQL Server Geometry. STPointN(2) - STX and STY values

Tags: sql-server, geometry, utm

I am looking for ways to identify polygons that were in UTM zones while they were inserted in a SQL Server table with shape as their geometry column.  Meanwhile some of the other states had inserted the records as 4326 (geographic coordinates system WGS 1984).

I was trying to a query

```
select top 10 shape.STPointN(2).STX as [Longitude], shape.STPointN(2).STY as [Latitude], shape.AsText()
from myTable
where shape.STPoint(2).STX > 180
```

The above query brought back no records.  Reason for me to do this is because of an issue I am facing:

When I view this myTable from ArcCatalog 10.7.1 using an SDE connection to the SQL Server, I am able to see all the records and when I drag and drop the layer into ArcMap 10.7.1 from the same SDE connection,  I miss many of the records.

ArcMap 10.7.1 defines the extent as 649185.719, 3006426.602 and it took some time for me to realize that the polygon features 'messing' us up could be in UTM.

So I wanted to isolate those records inside SQL Server table with UTM values thinking that they are in decimal degrees 4326 projection even though they are in UTM.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: So have you tried querying for records where shape.STSrid != 4326?